# Guaranteed Delivery of Messages with Active MQ and WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2

Issue: i have a proxy service which consumes only XML message, but sometimes if we  are getting  XML  message with not proper format,just syntax error,our proxy should send that message to  a different  queue,the message should not loss.

```
i have followed the below link but unable to get the expected output
https://www.yenlo.com/blog/guaranteed-message-deliveries-part-3-monitoring-the-redelivery-policy

 Below  is my proxy:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="RollbackProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="jms" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
           <log description="" level="full">
                <property name="****************" value="******************************"/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence>
            <property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <log category="ERROR" level="full">
                <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="error_code"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="error_message"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_DETAIL" name="error_detail"/>
            </log>
        </faultSequence>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">QueueName</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
        <rules xmlns="">
            <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
            <default>application/xml</default>
        </rules>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
</proxy>


axis2.xml and activemq.xml i have  properly updated.
we are using active MQ.
Can somebody guide me on this?
Thanks in Advance
```

Comment: Do you need to rollback the message and get the message redelivered? If not you should remove the SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY or set it to false. In the fault sequence, you can send the message to a JMS endpoint using send mediator

Comment: Hi Asitha , we are accepting only xml message format  in our proxy, but sometimes some tags are missing from xml message ,so its not proper xml,we have to send any improper format message into a queue but we are not  able to log that message also. how can i send that improper message to any queue?

Comment: while logging that message only we are getting error,if i am sending to any endpoint(queue) ,the message is blank.  Error while logging:[2017-09-29 12:23:33,012] [] ERROR - LogMediator Could not build full log message: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </message>; expected </properties>.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [15,9]
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag </message>; expected </properties>.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [15,9]
        at